# Can not plus with #define variable directly

Tags: ios, objective-c

At top of my `ViewController`, I have define a `MESSAGE_SIZE` like this

```
#define IPHONE [UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone 
#define MESSAGE_SIZE IPHONE ? 12 : 13
```

Inside a method, I try to access to `MESSAGE_SIZE` by 2 ways. It seems the same but produce different result

```
float size = MESSAGE_SIZE + 2;
NSLog(@"size = %f",size);

float size2 = MESSAGE_SIZE;
float size3 = size2 + 2;
NSLog(@"size3 = %f",size3);
```

I test on IPHONE and here is the Log

```
2016-05-27 14:59:02.992 EarCrush[8278:135453] size = 12.000000
2016-05-27 14:59:02.992 EarCrush[8278:135453] size3 = 14.000000
```

Hope someone explains why this happened. Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocessor macros are fancy text-replacement commands.  What happens at compile time is that

```
float size = MESSAGE_SIZE + 2;
NSLog(@"size = %f",size);
```

becomes

```
float size = IPHONE ? 12 : 13 + 2;
NSLog(@"size = %f",size);
```

I assume that `IPHONE` evaluates to true, so you get `12`.

In the second case

```
float size2 = MESSAGE_SIZE;
float size3 = size2 + 2;
NSLog(@"size3 = %f",size3);
```

becomes

```
float size2 = IPHONE ? 12 : 13;  // 12
float size3 = size2 + 2;         // 14
NSLog(@"size3 = %f",size3);
```

You can improve your macro by use of parentheses.

```
#define MESSAGE_SIZE (IPHONE ? 12 : 13)
```

Now the first example becomes

```
float size = (IPHONE ? 12 : 13) + 2;
NSLog(@"size = %f",size);
```

which will give the expected answer of `14`.

Comment: `IPHONE` will also be expanded.

Comment: True, but not relevant to the answer.

Comment: thank you so much. now I understand why this happend

Comment: But confusing to the questioner, perhaps. They also need brackets around the `IPHONE` expression.

Comment: Not in this case.  As long as the entire ternary expression is surrounded, it will work.  If the `IPHONE` macro is used in other scenarios, the same need may apply.  The important thing is that this question and answer demonstrate the principle.  Readers are free to expand on its usage as they find necessary.